# Text inside input cutted with font family (ionic)

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I've a problem with a customized font used in an input field.

As you can see is cutted on top and on bottom.

[image]

There is no padding or margin. What could be the error?

[image]

[image]

I think is related to this div that doesn't appear in entire code.

Comment: Nice to see that only contribution of some users is to put down votes. You are really usefull.

Comment: people can only help you when you show them the actual css  classes attached to the html. your question is not properly asked.

Comment: There is no css related of this issue.

Comment: check the classes attached to the html element in question... provide a link the website, so i can use the inspector tool to analyse the problem... this problem has a very easy fix...

Comment: did you find the solution? i am using `SansSerif` font family and facing this issue. but with normal fonts it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the height is too small, but I could be wrong. Try setting the 'height' parameter to 50px and let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Nope, height is bigger enough.

Comment: you cannot solve this problem without information regarding css. @ClaudioƜǝısMulas , consider providing a link to your site, if you cant provide the actual css.

Answer (score 0):

The span surrounding the `<input>` is an inline element. I suspect this is what is causing the issue. Try to change the `<span>` to `display: block`

Comment: Thanks but nothing changed :(

Comment: @ClaudioƜǝısMulas one of the parent elements surround the `<input>` must have `overflow: hidden`. Are you able to use the dev tools to inspect each of the parent elements to see if this is the case?